# Roots of a 6-degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find the roots of the equation $$2000x^6+100x^5+10x^3+x-2=0.$$ I am struggling finding a root using rational root theorem. Even if I get a root, I have to find all the roots. Please don't use WolframAlpha, I am looking for an approach, etc. Thanks.